# How to make hair dynamics work with surface deform modifier and cloth simulation to make a blanket with tassles?

Tags: modifiers, particles, cloth-simulation, hair

I'm trying to 'drop' a blanket with tassels onto a sofa using cloth simulation and am having trouble making the tassels behave realistically. I am using the surface deform modifier to deform the blanket using a simple subdivided plane, and am then applying the cloth simulation to that plane.

I have used a hair particle system to add fringes to the blanket, and have turned on hair dynamics. However, when I play the simulation, the blanket deforms fine but the fringes don't behave very dynamically. Either all the fringes stay in exactly the same orientation, or several of them end up facing upwards and in both cases they don't deform along their length at all, behaving more like solid rods than tassels.

Blend file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w_bRBRI3u-4e3KkCmDm77ibjpzIh4xNR/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: a blend file would help a lot...

Comment: @Chris Here's a link to the .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w_bRBRI3u-4e3KkCmDm77ibjpzIh4xNR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: with the file you sent the particles/hairs aren't falling at all....

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to bind the surface deform modifier again after I'd made some changes. It should work now: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w_bRBRI3u-4e3KkCmDm77ibjpzIh4xNR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does anyone have any advice on this? I've been battling with this for days, including trying the particle instance modifier, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with this problem, I successfully modeled the blanket with tassels by instancing the braided tassels onto the hair particle system using the particle instance modifier with the settings outlined here: [Getting instanced particles to follow paths of hairs in particle system with hair dynamics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213292/getting-instanced-particles-to-follow-paths-of-hairs-in-particle-system-with-hai/213353?noredirect=1#comment360160_213353)

*Edit:* For the sake of completeness, it is worth noting that the issue here in this question is about the fact that the blanket has **normals that point in the wrong direction**. To flip them press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in *Edit* mode. After that, the tassel object needs to be rotated by 180° (X-axis: `-90`° → `90`°) so that it sticks out and not in the blanket. To make the tassel bent along the hair particle a *Particle Instance* modifier is needed (see linked question above).

[image: face orientation overlay]