# Getting instanced particles to follow paths of hairs in particle system with hair dynamics

Tags: modifiers, particles, hair, instances

I've created a plane with a hair particle system and with hair dynamics on. I then used a particle instance modifier to add a custom cylinder to each hair particle, and turned on both 'create along paths' and 'keep shape'. I then added a wind force field to displace the particle system and (I hoped) in turn the cylinders. However, the instanced particles remain stationary when I play the animation and do not follow the paths of the hair particles (which deform just fine). Is there any solution to this? Am I missing something obvious? Here's the .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qqP-HdKrQP_uk3MMPlcxnhdnoKtU7yi7/view?usp=sharing
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost did it, just a few things to fix:

- decimate the number of faces of the cylinder with the *Decimate* modifier, un-subdivide. The faces get multiplied by each particle. In *Object mode*, right-click the object and select *Shade Smooth*, and will look the same with only 300 vertices, that's 1/10th.
- ***lay down the cylinder along the Y-axis*** by a -90° rotation around the X-axis in *Object mode*, **apply the *Rotation*** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>). Make sure that the cylinder's origin is at bottom of the mesh, at world origin. Apply *Location* if needed.
- In *Edit* mode, **move 3D Cursor to world origin** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), select all vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>), and select from menu: ***Mesh* → *Sort Elements...* → *Cursor Distance***. This prevents strange things from happening as the particles bend and twist due to a change in wind direction.
  [image: layout of particle object]
  <sup>layout of particle object</sup>
- Change the settings of the *Particle Instance* modifier: (*Pole Axis*: `Z`, set *Position:* `1.000`, clear *Keep Shape* checkbox)
  [image: Particle Instance settings]

Particles in the wind:
[image: particles in the wind]

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed answer! I'll give this a go tomorrow.

Comment: It worked perfectly with your instructions, thanks again!

Comment: If it's okay to post a follow-up question on here, could you help me with one more thing? I've applied the above principles to a blanket with tassels falling onto some cushions. I've added tassels to the blanket using the particle instance modifier and then used the surface deform modifier to bind the mesh to a subdivided plane (to which the cloth simulation is being applied). But when I start the simulation, the fringes fly off and distort instead of moving as you would expect them to. Here's the .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iYh7nYED2lEQ6EZdO4opqZgDfmqrCpS_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you're welcome! It's better when you post this as a separate question because this site is a Q&A site. The structure is one question + one or more answers. This makes it easier for people who have the same or similar problem to find the question and get a solution. Feel free to post it and I can answer it. Teaser: Have a look at scale and location ;-)

Comment: Oh wait! Never mind, you did that already here: [How to make hair dynamics work with surface deform modifier and cloth simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211979/how-to-make-hair-dynamics-work-with-surface-deform-modifier-and-cloth-simulation) a while ago.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, of course it was the scale! It usually is hahaha now everything works perfectly.